# form auto submits multiple times

Tags: java, javascript, html

I need to send a few hidden variable to the struts controller on auto submit of the form. I am sending the  variables just fine but since I have the form submit in the document on ready function. The form re submits infinitely . I need to stop the submit after first time submit . Any suggestions ? Below is what I tried.

Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready (function () { 
document.getElementById ('action').value ='hello';
document.getElementById ('myform').submit ();
})
</script>

<form action="/rlogin" id="myform">
<input type=hidden id=user value=you>
<input type=hidden id=action />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check weither a variable created after the submit has been created or not.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    if (typeof mySent == 'undefined') {
        document.getElementById ('action').value ='hello'; 
        document.getElementById ('myform').submit ();
        mySent = true;
    }
}
```